# Getting inside the entries and keys of objects or objects of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

I just started dealing with objects and i have no clue how i´m getting inside those nested objects.
Let me show you how i tried:

```
  $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "Bibliothek.json",
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(Object.entries(response,"objects"));
            console.log(Object.values(response,"values"));

        var entry1 = Object.entries(response,"objects");
        var entry2 = Object.entries(entry1,"entry1");
        var entry3 = Object.entries(entry2,"entry2");

        console.log(entry1,"entry1");
        console.log(entry2,"entry2");
        console.log(entry3,"entry3");

        var mainkey = Object.values(response);
        var types = Object.values(mainkey);
        var files = Object.values(types);

        console.log(mainkey,"mainkey");
        console.log(types,"types");
        console.log(files,"files");

        },
    });
```

This is what i get, so how do i get into Attribute:Array(1) for example?

[image: console]

The first repsonse from the success looks like that:

[image]

EDIT: The response log +
JSON file im reading: https://pastebin.com/wiqajA4P

[image]

Comment: If you could edit this post to include the result of **console.log(response)** we can show you how to navigate the resultant object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access any of the entities which are in **Arrays** you need to reference their index (0,1,2,3) etc. With object properties, you can access these via their object key.

So looking at your attached image, which property are you attempting to access?

The first object is located at Geraetewelten, so can be accessed using the dot notation

```
response.Geraetewelten
```

You can continue to follow this to reach the **Atrribute** array (Listed as Array(1) meaning it has 1 child.

as this is an array you can access the child by index starting at 0

so this would be

```
response.Geraetewelten.Atrribute[0]
```

etc.

Comment: Good morning and thank you very much this worked out for me.